# How to restrict a formula from returning more than a maximum value

Tags: google-sheets, max

I’ve read all the hints but can’t find the solution. I thought I had it but the cell kept returning an error message.

I’m looking to restrict a formula from returning a result larger than 3

Current cell formula is `=(0.25*F10)`.

Tried `=Max 3,(.25*F10)` with no luck

I could really use some help here please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please tag your  questions with the tags corresponding to the technologies that you are using. I assume for this post it is Excel.

Comment: No it’s Google sheets. I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `3` within the brackets and to use `min` instead of `max`: `=min(3,0.25*F10)`

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanh you all for the quick responses

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
=if(0.25 x F10>3,3,0.25 x F10)
```

The x is used to represent the multiply sign